Landscaping under Ash Trees
I have 3 Ash trees in the easement between my sidewalk and the street. I removed the grass in the hopes of xeriscaping under the trees.
PROBLEM 1: I now have weeds and grass patches amongst the dirt that have been hard to eradicate because of the tree roots so close to the surface. How can I eradicate them?
PROBLEM 2: ongoing maintenance If I deep mulch will this prevent the tree roots from getting oxygen? Guidance or advice please! Thank you!!

What kind of ash trees, and where in the world do you live?In North America?

Central Oregon, high desert

Problem 3 - Emerald Ash Borer, which will (probably) be along to kill your trees at some point.
Mulch is fine, go take a walk in some woods. What you don't want to do is change the soil level (at all, or perhaps by more than 1/2 inch - 1.2 cm.) Pull whatever weeds you can and cut the rest, then put ~6" of loose mulch down. If you removed soil while removing the grass, replace it without overdoing that.
If there are any piles or bags of leaves that have not been hauled away in the neighborhood, go ask if you can take them for mulching. Run a lawnmower over a few inches of leaves spread out unless you have a more dedicated shredding/grinding tool to chop them up. Shredded leaves stay put better than whole leaves. If you have any neighbors who collect leaves by mowing them with a bagger attached, make friends and get them pre-shredded (assuming they throw them away otherwise.)

Thank you, this confirms my intended approach.
